# Edit TextField with value already filled doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner with React JS and I'm doing a test project to train my skills.

I have a list of farms being rendered on the screen. The user can click on the button to register a new farm or can click on the property to be able to edit the existing property.

In a single Dialog Modal I do both. The problem is when I try to edit the Input field, it is not working. It doesn't matter what I type and nothing happens.

That's  my input field, I'm using `TextField` from React Material:

```js
<TextField
  id="farmer-name"
  label="Farm Name"
  value={propertyData.farmerName}
  onChange={(event) =>
    changeField("farmerName", propertyData.id, event.target.value)
  }
  className={classes.input}
  InputProps={{
    className: classes.inputContent
  }}
  InputLabelProps={{
    className: classes.inputLabel
  }}
/>
```

And here's my function that will be able update my data:

```js
const changeField = (field, id, value) => {
  const newPropertyData = { ...propertyData };
  if (newPropertyData.id === id) {
    newPropertyData.field = value;
  }
};
```

Here's my code, I put in CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-breeze-xnv3r?file=/src/index.js

[Screen of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC6Or.png)

Can someone help me to edit that´s values? Thanks

Comment: use `useState` to update the values inside the TextFiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually changing the `propertyData` stored in the `useState` hook.

Currently, there will be a new property added called `field` in the `newPropertyData` object. However, this variable is never used or stored and you probably don't want the value to be stored in the `field` property.

The shortest answer is to pass a function to the `setPropertyData` which will receive the previous value of `propertyData`.

The previous propertyData can be extended with a dynamic property by using the following syntax:  `[field]: value`.

```
  const changeField = (field, id, value) => {
    if (propertyData.id === id) {
      setPropertyData(data => ({ ...data, [field]: value }));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You should save state on change in text field

```
const changeField = (field, id, value) => {
  const newPropertyData = { ...propertyData };
  if (newPropertyData.id === id) {
     // change field value for specific id
     newPropertyData[field] = value;
   }
   // set updated field value into state to show on form
   setPropertyData(newPropertyData);
};
```

Comment: Hey Awais and Ashok, that's works for me also!! Thanks